# is it possible to read data from a file, one bit at a time in ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary

i have been looking at file formats, like png and mp3, and they are stored on a bit by bit basis. in the past i've been able to read bits by reading an entire byte, then splitting it into seperate bits. I can't do this for png because the length of the chunks that data is stored in arn't evenly divisible by eight (bits)

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case of PNGs, you really should look at [chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png). For a nice use of this library, see [Pure Ruby colored blob detection](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/pure-ruby-colored-blob-detection/). Looking at the source on GitHub should also tell you more about the chunked reading.

Comment: well, i'm not particularly interested in png's, i really just wanted to know how to read bit by bit, and didn't particularly want to look through other peoples source.

Comment: O.O i just re-read the png documentation, and its BYTES not bits. so i actually have no need to read/write on a bit by bit basis yet

Comment: :-) As I said, if you ever really have to deal with PNGs, check out the above library, it's cool.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, not in Ruby, nor in any other programmimng language.

And, btw, you will hardly find a file whose length is not a multiple of 8 bit.